# Table MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have used WPAllImport to import data from a CSV-file to Advanced Custom Fields.
I now want to put them back together with a SQL query, but dont know how to do it.

I've tried WPDataTables, but when I choose 5 or more tables, WPDataTables stops.
If I pick 2, I get this code

```
SELECT posts_podukter.post_title AS podukter_post_title,
       podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl.meta_value AS podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris
FROM beta_h3L_posts AS posts_podukter
  INNER JOIN (SELECT podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_posts.ID as id, meta_value, meta_key  FROM beta_h3L_postmeta AS podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_postmeta  INNER JOIN beta_h3L_posts AS podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_posts   ON podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_postmeta.post_id = podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_posts.ID   AND podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl_posts.post_type = 'podukter') AS podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl
     ON podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl.meta_key = 'produkter_0_pris' AND podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris_tbl.id = posts_podukter.ID 
WHERE 1=1 
   AND posts_podukter.post_type = 'podukter'
```

I think this is too much code. 
Can someone help me to get on the right way.... :-)

This is what the table should look like

Here is a capture how the table should look like
[image: Here is a capture how the table should look like]

Comment: If you give us sample data and/or table structures we can help

Comment: I've added a screenshot from the original table in my first post. Do you want more info? :-)

Comment: We need to see what the base tables look like, before they are joined

Comment: Table1: Productnames with links
Table2: Prices
Table3: Priceoffers
Table4: Percentoffers
Table5: Availability
Table6: Storename
Table7: Shippinginfo
Table8: Tags/Categories
Table9: A random number

Comment: Well, we agree on something.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that this is "too much code" which sounds sort of ridiculous, but in this case totally applies. That SQL statement that was produced could be written as:

```
    SELECT 
        post.post_title as podukter_post_title,
        postmeta.meta_value as podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris       
    FROM beta_h3L_posts AS posts
        INNER JOIN beta_h3L_postmeta AS postmeta  
            ON postmeta.post_id = post.ID
            AND postmeta.meta_key = 'produkter_0_pris'          
    WHERE posts.post_type = 'podukter'
```

If there is another metavalue that you need you can join again to your meta table:

```
    SELECT 
        post.post_title as podukter_post_title,
        postmeta.meta_value as podukter_meta_produkter_0_pris,
        postmeta2.meta_value as tilbudspris
    FROM beta_h3L_posts AS posts
        INNER JOIN beta_h3L_postmeta AS postmeta  
            ON postmeta.post_id = post.ID
            AND postmeta.meta_key = 'produkter_0_pris'  
        INNER JOIN beta_h3L_postmeta AS postmeta2 
            ON postmeta.post_id = post.ID
            AND postmeta2.meta_key = 'tilbudspris'          
    WHERE posts.post_type = 'podukter'
```

I don't know what any of these words mean (besides post and postmeta) so I'm just going to assume that this is right/helpful.

The only thing is that you *may* want to switch to using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your `postmeta` table just in case the `meta_key` you are after doesn't exist for the `post.id` you are querying. In that case, with an `INNER JOIN` the `id`/`post` will be dropped from the result set where a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will show the `id`/`post` record with a blank for whatever that corresponding `meta_value` is that you are joining in.